# What is the best approach to extend SystemConfiguration.yml in TAF

Tags: configuration, taf

**Note:** I originally asked this as an Issue in Github but then realized it makes more sense to ask in here

We are setting up a box for continuous integration testing for our multiple Magento solutions. As each project would have a different mix of modules and customizations we are shipping each project with their own unique tests and run the appropriate test suite for each along with the Core test suite (common for all of them). That much is easy.

The only problem we are not sure how to address is that each module comes with their own panel in the System->Configuration area and we would need to set up the UI mapping for each. However, as far as we can tell, there is only one unique UI map for the whole configuration area. It would be awesome to have some merging mechanism (as there is in every XML configuration in Magento) but as far as I can tell, there is none.

So, other than copying and tweaking SystemConfiguration.yml for each project, is there any way to "add" information to it without actually modifying it?

Answer (score 3):

So I got a response from MTAF. Turns out there is a built in mechanism to do just what I wanted to do.

Here's the official solution https://github.com/magento/taf/issues/15#issuecomment-17801585